# How to search directory and subdirectories based on a text file with partial filenames and copy those files to new directory

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I am trying to search a directory and sub directories for files listed in a text file and copy them to a new location using a batch file. I can get it work if I put the files I need in the main directory but I can't get it to search the sub directories.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%j in (filelist.txt) do (
 for /r "E:\Source"  %%a in ("%%j") do (
    copy "%%a" "C:\Destination\%%k"
 )
)
```

This works if I only want to search the "Source" folder but I cannot search any folders inside of the "Source" folder. Hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing.

I'm new to this so please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: what is the structure of the file with the target file names?

Comment: Your tag is powershell, but you present a batch-file. So what are you after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started, should you choose to use Powershell.

```
$files = 'C:\list.txt'
$location = 'C:\files\'
$destination = 'C:\destination\'

# for each filename in "list.txt", look for the file in C:\destination\, recursively
gc $files | % {
    write-host "looking for $_"

    $result = gci -Recurse $location $_

    if($result) {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "found $_ in $location!"
        write-host "copying $_ to $destination..."
        copy-item $result.FullName $destination\$_
    }
}
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

The `-Recurse` flag helps you with your issues traversing subdirectories.

You may need to optimize this approach to eliminate running the search once per filename, though on a small scale, this will do nicely.

Comment: Please use `Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ($_.Name)`. You are now constantly treating the FileInfo object `$_` as just a string containing nothing but the file name..

Comment: As in `copy-item $result.FullName (join-path $destination $_.Name)`? This would work but why is this preferred?

Comment: Your (and OPs) approach presumes only one occurence of the current file in `$location` and will otherwise overwrite the file in destination?

Comment: Good point. This is still a suitable starting point given we do not (and rarely ever will) know all conditions the OP will need to account for. If the OP mentions this is a need, we can include additional logic, or an alternative approach.